# Mongodb arithmetic expression of elements inside an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d0712368ff072a56a66e8"),
    "a" : {
        "nodes" : [
            {
                "b" : 1
            },
            {
                "c" : {
                    "nodes" : [
                        {
                            "d" : 2
                        },
                        {
                            "e" : 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "r" : 1
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d0712368ff072a56a66e9"),
        "a" : {
            "nodes" : [
                {
                    "b" : 4
                },
                {
                    "c" : {
                        "nodes" : [
                            {
                                "e" : 9
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "r" : 2
    }
```

Above are the sample documents, I want to find the **sum of a.nodes.b * a.nodes.c.nodes.d * a.nodes.c.nodes.e**
I have tried many pipelines, but not able to generalize the aggregation. Any help would be appreciated. 
nodes array can be present again at any level. If I get the solution for this, I will try to generalize the aggregation pipeline.

MongoDB **version 3.2**

Expected calculation and output
**(1 * 2 * 2) + (4 * 0 * 9) = 4**

Comment: Please add the best of your attempts to the question, expected output, and confirm key names `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible to handle "nodes array can be present again at any level." with aggregation.

With map-reduce it could be something like this:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){ 
        let reducer = (result, node) => {            
            Object.keys(node).map(key => {
                if (typeof node[key] === "object") {
                    if (node[key].nodes && Array.isArray(node[key].nodes)) {
                        result = node[key].nodes.reduce(reducer, result);
                    }
                } else {
                    result.product = result.product * node[key];
                    result.keys.add(key);
                }
            });
            return result;
        };        
        let {product, keys} = this.a.nodes.reduce(reducer, {product: 1, keys: new Set()});        
        emit(null, {product, keys: Array.from(keys)}) 
    },
    function(key, values){ 
        return values.reduce((total, item) => {
            let totalSum = total.sum, itemSum = item.product;
            for (let key of item.keys) if (!total.keys.includes(key)) totalSum = 0;
            for (let key of total.keys) if (!item.keys.includes(key)) itemSum = 0;

            return {sum: totalSum + itemSum, keys: Array.from(new Set([...total.keys, ...item.keys]))};
        }, {sum: 0, keys: []}).sum;
    },
    { query: { "a.nodes": { $exists: true } } , out: { inline: 1 }}
);
```

Map function recursively multiplies all keys, reducer checks the keys and calculate totals.